# Resize a table to the size of outter div

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

I created a table within div. The div tag is set style as float left. the table is overflow on the div. How can I do this? Please see below my html.

Sorry. The english is not my mother language. I mean I would like to fit the table within div. If the div will be small, the table and their fonts will be small automatically until the whole table will show within div.

**[reformed]**

I would like the table and it's content (mostly the font-size) to resize to the outter container. Is this possible ?

**[html]**

```
 <div style="border:1px solid black;width:20%;float:left;margin: 1% 2% 1% 2%; height:30%;">
     <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="7"><label for="">1</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sun</td>
                <td>Mon</td>
                <td>Thu</td>
                <td>Web</td>
                <td>Thurs</td>
                <td>Fri</td>
                <td>Sat</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: "How can i do this?" How can you do what?

Comment: Sorry. The english is not my mother language. I mean I would like to fit the table within div. If the div will be small, the table and their fonts will be small automatically until the whole table will show within div.

Comment: you may be looking for this: http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please add following style so that you will see scroll-bar in div

```
div {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

If you don't want to show scroll-bar then use following:

```
 div {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tested it. The table dose not be overflow on div. But they won't show the whole table. I would like to fix the table in div. I mean the table and font automatically will be small relevant with div size.

Comment: @zanhtet But its not necessary because if table contains much more content then we decrease the font size upto some extent. So its not acceptable situatuion.